# How to change bottom line color of EditText in Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext

I have tried changing my edit text bottom color various of ways but it doesn't change. I do not want to use drawable.

here is my xml and the methods I have tried using.

method one:

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
```

method two:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorPrimary</item>

</style>

</resources>
```

Here's my xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res /android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:id="@+id/b"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.example.isaac.loginexamples.b">

<RelativeLayout
    android:background="#009688"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/relative_half_screen_height">
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    card_view:cardElevation="18dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/card_view_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/card_view_height">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/header_logo_two"
            android:background="#22313F"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/view_header_height"></View>

        <View
            android:background="@drawable/shadow"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_logo_two"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="7dp"></View>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/logo_two"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/logo_image_width_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_image_width_height" />

        <EditText
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/logo_two"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
            android:layout_below="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried those two methods that I have seen online but it doesn't work. I am running the latest version of Android Studio. I hope there is a solution.
NOTE: I DO NOT WANT TO USE A DRAWABLE.
Thank you very much !

Comment: Maybe you should use the drawable xD

Comment: Maybe but you know, I rather use the AppCompat. I think its more nice and more reliable. @Beloo

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use drawable, you can use "View" below edittext and change the color of that `View` based on focuschange of edittext

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/username_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/size_1"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/username"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/username"
    android:layout_below="@+id/username"
    android:background="@color/grey"/>
```

within your activity or fragment, add these lines of code that takes care of changing the color of view based on username focus change

```
@OnFocusChange(R.id.username)
void onUserNameFocusChanged(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if (userNameView != null) {
        int focusViewColor = hasFocus ? getResources().getColor(R.color.red) : getResources().getColor(R.color.grey);
        userNameView.setBackgroundColor(focusViewColor);
    }
}
```